# Something is wrong with my python write to interact game code

Tags: python

When I try to run this code, nothing happens. Please help.

Code:

```
def game() :
    import time
    import random
    print ("you whake up in a forest. you see a stick next to you. What do you do?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("(go north)|(go west)|(pick up stick(recomended))|(go east)")
    a = str(input("your move: "))

    if a == "go north" :
        print ("you went north")
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("a wolf aproaches you")
        time.sleep (1)
        b = str(input("what do you do?: "))
    if b == "run" :
        print ("you tried, but the wolf was faster. You died ")
        c= str(input("Try again? (Yes/No)"))
    if c == "yes" :
        game()
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you call `game()`, aside from the recursive call.

Comment: I think you will rapidly find the error if you create a [mcve].

Comment: you have not called the `game()` function anywhere except for recursion...  at end the end of the code write `game()`  outside the function and then run again.

Answer (score 1):

All the `def` does is define the function - it doesn't call it.

You probably want something like this at the end of your file so you can call it as a script

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

This will let you run it as a script and it will invoke your `game()` function, but it also allows you to import it without any side effects.

```
from foo import game
```

As a side note you have some indentation issues with your code. If `if b` needs to be one indent in so that it will only run once b has been defined - same with the `if c`. If you run it as it is it will complain about undefined variables.